# Translating HTML string from English to German using MicrosoftTranslator v3 using Java

Tags: java, translate

Translating HTML string from English to German using MicrosoftTranslator v3 REST service. below is given example html string, actual html string has more than 90k char.
Here there is a difference in html string before and after translation for example newline '\n' is added afyter  tag "\n" and other changes. how do i avoid these extra char?

System.out.println(HTMLStringBeforeTranslation); 
// Take advantage of the fact that the same sentence can have two different structures. This famous joke from Groucho Marx assumes that most people expect the structure of the first part to be

System.out.println(HTMLStringAfterTranslation); 
// \n Nutzen Sie die Tatsache, dass der gleiche Satz zwei verschiedene Strukturen haben kann. Dieser berühmte Witz von Groucho Marx geht davon aus, dass die meisten Menschen erwarten, dass die Struktur des ersten Teils\n

Code:

```
public class Translator {
    static String subscriptionKey = "Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    static String host = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";
    static String path = "/translate?api-version=3.0";

public static class RequestBody {
    String Text;

    public RequestBody(String textpass) {
        this.Text = textpass;  // text; // htmlText;
    }
}

        public static String TranslateHtml (String rawHtml) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL (host + path + params);

        List<RequestBody> objList = new ArrayList<RequestBody>();
        objList.add(new RequestBody(rawHtml));
        String content = new Gson().toJson(objList);

        return Posthtml(url, content).toString();
    }

    public static JsonElement Posthtml (URL url, String content) throws Exception {
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //connection.setRequestProperty("textType", "html");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");  // "application/json"   "text/html"

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", content.length() + "");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-ClientTraceId", java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        byte[] encoded_content = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
        wr.write(encoded_content, 0, encoded_content.length);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder ();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(response.toString());
        JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray();

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(array.get(0).toString());
        JsonElement element2 = obj.get("translations");
JsonObject obj2 = (JsonObject) parser.parse(element2.getAsJsonArray().get(0).toString());
        return obj2.get("text");
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

    static String text2 = "Take advantage of the fact that the same sentence can have two different structures. This famous joke from Groucho Marx assumes that most people expect the structure of the first part to be";

    static String htmlText = new String("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><font color= 'red'>" + text2 + "</font></body></html>");

     try {
System.out.println(TranslateHtml (htmlText));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Most of the time an extra newline does not change the way the HTML is rendered. Does this also happen in situations where the newline makes a difference (e.g. inside a `pre` element)?